# Chartist.js Responsive

Tags: javascript, responsive, chartist.js

I have a horizontal chartist bar. It looks ok on desktop, however in mobile version (below than 480px), it gets much smaller. I've looked at chartist responsive options on its website, however, I couldn't implemented responsive options in my js code. I would like to show it bigger enough in mobile version. I am open to make the bar-chart vertical in mobile version.

```
 $('#section-sk').waypoint(function(direction){
    if(direction === 'down'){
      $('.js-animation-2').addClass('animated fadeInUp')


      var myChart = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
        labels: ['Text-7', 'Text-6', 'Text-5', 'Text-4', 'Text-3', 'Text-2', 'Text1'],
        series: [
        [
        {meta: 'Something', value: 50},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 80},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 100},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 75},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 15},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 80},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 40}
        ]
        ]
      }, {

      horizontalBars: true,
      low: 10,
      high: 100,
      axisY: {
        offset: 75
      },

      axisX: {
        offset: 50,
        type: Chartist.FixedScaleAxis,
        ticks: [10,20, 30,40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
      },

      plugins: [
      Chartist.plugins.tooltip()
      ]
    });
```

Comment: Can you specify the link that you are checking on desktop and on mobile browser? Otherwise it would be difficult for people to test and comment. 
It will also be better if you attack full screenshots (for both).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var myChart = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
        labels: ['Text-7', 'Text-6', 'Text-5', 'Text-4', 'Text-3', 'Text-2', 'Text1'],
        series: [
        [
        {meta: 'Something', value: 50},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 80},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 100},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 75},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 15},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 80},
        {meta: 'Something', value: 40}
        ]
        ]
      }, {

      horizontalBars: true,
      low: 10,
      high: 100,
      axisY: {
        offset: 75
      },

      axisX: {
        offset: 50,
        type: Chartist.FixedScaleAxis,
        ticks: [10,20, 30,40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100],
      }
      },[
  // Options override for media < 480px
  ['screen and (max-width: 480px)', {
    reverseData: true,
    horizontalBars: true,
    ticks: [20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
  }]
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/master/dist/chartist.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/master/dist/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ct-chart ct-square"></div>
```